# Broadcast node's address on local network in Erlang or Elixir so others can find it

Tags: erlang, elixir

I have a bunch of workers on a local network, which must each talk to a master node. That master node may change from time to time, and the workers must therefore "follow" it. In Python I can do this by constantly broadcasting the master node IP address on UDP on my local network, and this works really well:

```
import socket
import time

cs = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
cs.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
cs.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
while True:
    cs.sendto(b"Bossman server address", ('255.255.255.255', 8477)) # broadcast my address!
    time.sleep(1)
```

And on the worker side:

```
def t3master():

""" thread which continuously updates the master ip address """
global masterip
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(('', 8477))
while True:
    msg = s.recvfrom(1024)
    masterip = msg[1][0]
```

How can I do this in Erlang or Elixir? So:

a) can this be done without UDP broadcasting? ie does OTP provide this facility? And if not...

b) How to I broadcast and receive UDP in Erlang or Elixir as per the above Python methodology?

Comment: Have you checked out gen_udp? http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_udp.html

Comment: Erlang or Elixir in this case may have substantial differences in terms of implementation. Which one are you trying to use?

Comment: I am trying to use Elixir but I can easily translate an Erlang solution.

Comment: Why not use a fixed DNS for master node?

Comment: @Kevin Johnson 'cos I may not have access to a DNS server, or I may be doing this offsite where I have no access to a DNS server, and this is anyway easier than maintaining a DNS because I can move the server around easily and fast without ANY reconfiguration of anything.